# Is there a word for (computer) keyboard keys that have a valley in them, like caps lock?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sorry if the title isn't clear. Some keyboards will put a pit/valley thing on certain keys to put some extra space between the key and its neighbor. A common one is on Caps lock, presumably so you don't accidentally press it when you want to press "A". I think I have also seen it on the "Enter" key. Is there a word for this type of key, or the characteristic?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no extra space there on my keyboard.

Comment: I suppose you might say "irregular profile" or "irregularly shaped".

Comment: @HotLicks the 2nd photo is from my own keyboard (first is a stock photo) and its only on 1 of my many keyboards. I think its more common on older keyboards with taller keys, newer keyboards have shorter keys so its not feasible to make the valley

Comment: mechanical keyboards still have taller keys, so I think you typically only see it on certain mechanical keyboards, or the other variant, buckling spring keyboards (thats what the 2nd photo is)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From reading 
https://deskthority.net/wiki/Caps_lock the term *step* seems promising, so perhaps *stepped keycaps* or *keycaps with a step*?

I don't know how "official" the term is but that website has an amazing amount of information on keyboards and [keycaps](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keycap) and seems as authoritative as I can find.
[image: keysboard]

And from same page ...

> It usually occupies a prominent place between Tab, Shift and A, and is easily engaged by mistake when reaching for A. To avoid this mistake, many keyboards have a **stepped caps lock keycap** that places a gap between caps lock and the adjacent letter key.

Comment: Makes sense! It looks like a little stair step. The provided link was helpful as well