# Single-word noun for something changing width

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a noun to describe the situation where something is changing width. Have a look at this hypothetical window frame:

[image: Window frame with two panes of uneven height.]

**Window Frame with Two Panes of Uneven Height**

The bottom part of the frame changes width across the window. What might I call the category of windows where this occurs?

I have thought about "widening," but am not overly fond of it, since it might go from wide to narrow, or you could even have a situation with more panes, where it is wide-narrow-wide. Any ideas?

Comment: width adjustment?

Comment: I would be worried that could indicate I am doing something to adjust the width, whereas I am merely trying describe the situation where the width is not constant.

Comment: "Stepped width"; broadly, "Stepped section"; of even just "stepped".

Comment: So https://s3.amazonaws.com/answer-board-image/20094292213266337664000656250005238.jpg

Comment: They're windows _of variable width_ or _of varying width_, depending on the sentence you want to use them in. I don't think you will find a single word for this.

Comment: I like stepped width (or stepped frame or something along those lines) quite a lot. And the illustration showing that it can be used elsewhere in describing building parts is a good bonus. Thanks! Feel free to add an answer I can accept.

Comment: Note that "stepped" usually indicates something that changes in chunks rather than continuously. So if the width changes in, say, blocks of 5 pixels, it would be stepped, but if it changes down to pixel-resolution, it wouldn't be. Having said that, I don't know what you mean by *"The bottom part of the frame changes width across the window"* as nothing in the picture suggests any width change...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Think of the bottom two lines of the diagram as the lower horizontal member of the window frame. It is narrow from the left end up to the center of the window, after which it broadens and continues right to the right end. Whereas, the left and right vertical members and the top horizontal member are of uniform cross-section (width or thickness as you may call it).

Comment: The OP appears to need a whole glossary. The bottom piece in question is called a *rail*. It doesn't change width, it changes height, if you want to say that; or you can refer to the rail's cross-section in terms of *molded* and *sided* dimensions. Or you can refer to the *face* of the rail being stepped.

Comment: @PhilSweet "Rail" is not the term for the frame member. "Width" works, as either of the dimensions.

Comment: @Kris It is where I come from, but if you don't believe me, try [here](https://www.wdma.com/page/TheWindowGlossary)

Comment: @PhilSweet I don't think "rail" is used for a frame member ever, only of a sash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window frames could be of uniform cross-section or rarely, with a change in width half-way.

Such an abrupt change in width is usually called a "step" and a member with its section having one or more such "steps" may be called a "stepped section".

For a visualization, consider the case of a "[stepped beam](https://s3.amazonaws.com/answer-board-image/20094292213266337664000656250005238.jpg)" (Chegg via Google).

Comment: I agree with this. See similar question on keyboard keys at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418986/is-there-a-word-for-computer-keyboard-keys-that-have-a-valley-in-them-like-ca/418999#418999